# Java Mail download large IMAP messages

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

We have an application which uses Java Mail to send and download email messages from Office 365. When downloading large email messages (20+ Mb) IMAP never seems to complete the download. When switching to POP3 then the emails download fine. Are there any properties I can adjust to rectify this issue? Any other advice is also welcome and thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?  You can try setting the [`mail.imap.fetchsize`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html#mail.imap.fetchsize) or [`mail.imap.partialfetch`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html#mail.imap.partialfetch) properties to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I disabled mail.imap.partialfetch and the messages downloaded in under 2 minutes where they previously took 30 minutes. It's major improvement. Are there any pitfalls to using this property?

Comment: Yes.  It needs enough memory to hold the entire message.  the default only reads a buffer at a time, which limits the memory use if you process the data as a stream.